# How to get the ID value while the radio button is checked in Shopify?

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid

I have a radio button group and one input field. What I want is when the radio button property is CHECKED the below ID gets their value. I tried something which is wrong.

```html
<input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male" checked>
<label for="male">Male</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
<label for="female">Female</label><br>

<input type="text" id="{%if radio.checked='checked'%} Account {%endif%}" class="">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need input box value as selected radio button value.  if you change the id of input control then HTML page will have 2 controls with same id. If you want input control value to show selected radio value then use below code.

```
<script language="javascript">

function onCheck(isChecked, value){
    document.getElementById('displaySelRad').value = value
}

</script>


    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male" checked onclick="onCheck(this.checked, this.value)">
    <label for="male">Male</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female" onclick="onCheck(this.checked, this.value)">
    <label for="female">Female</label><br>

    <input type="text" id="displaySelRad" class="">
```